# What do the labels JD, JL and ES mean?

Tags: github

I always see these tags in the issues and pull requests on Github but do not know the meaning and find it hard to search for.

For example, in this [famous Caffe project.](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/labels)

Comment: It probably would help to see these labels in context. Can you provide (or link to) examples? (Having a rep below 10 gives you limited rights and you may not be able to post active links - just leave out the colon to render the links non-active: `http//example.com` - I'll be happy to restore these to active links for you)

Comment: @FreeRadical thanks for the reply. the added is an example that i meet recently.

Comment: @user5302 Do you have any other examples of projects that employ these labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are custom labels. In the example you give, they seem to be the initials of developers.

Looking at the project's [page](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), the lead developer is called Evan Shelhamer (ES). JD seems to be a contributor named Jeff Donahue. JL would be contributor Jon Long. All these people are mentioned on the project's page, under "The BVLC members who have contributed to Caffe are ..."
In other words, not just contributors, but people from the Berkeley Vision and Learning Centre (BVLC) itself - people with leader(-like) positions on the project.

Comment: oh. I checked the contributor names. looks like you are right. sry for the confusion:)